# how printf know what to print out after sign extension

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char i = -128; 
    int j = i; 
    printf("%d %u\n", j, j); 
   return 0;
}
```

result is `-128 4294967168`

what I think is

```
i: 10000000
```

and after the assignment operator, do the sign extension

```
j: 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
```

what I want to ask is how `printf("%d",j)` know to print `-128` just use

the last byte? How it works?

Thx!

Comment: Do you really get `-127` printed?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler yes I really get it.

Comment: Very interesting; what hardware are you running on?  When I compile on Mac OS X 10.7.4 with `-fsigned-char`, I get `-128 4294967168` (both of which differ by one from what you report seeing); when I compile with `-funsigned-char`, I get `128 128`.  I don't see a legitimate way for a compiler to convert `-128` assigned to a `char` to `-127` when assigned to an `int`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It should be -127 in question, sorry!

Comment: That makes more sense!  Now you have to re-examine those bit-patterns.

Comment: I have correct it! Sorry about those stupid mistakes and thx for your help!I very appreciate it!

Comment: Note that the bit pattern for -127 is 0x81 (1000 0001), and that the sign extended integer is therefore 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0001. The last bit is a 1 (because -127 is an odd number), not 0 as in your examples.
Indeed, your bit patterns are correct for -128, which is why I was puzzled about the source code vs your output (where the source originally said `-128` instead of `-127`).

Comment: I've rewritten my answer since I originally misread your question. You might want to check whether you want to keep it accepted or accept a different answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what I want to ask is how printf("%d",j) know to print -128 just use the last byte?

It doesn't. It is told to print a signed `int`, so it takes the appropriate number of bytes -typically 4 nowadays - from the stack and interprets that bit pattern as a signed `int`.

When you assign a negative `char` to an `int` variable, as in `int j = i;` here, what happens is not really sign-extension, but - since all values a `char` can represent are also representable as an `int` - a value-preserving conversion, the `char` `i` is converted to an `int` with the same value.

On two's complement machines, which are by far the most common nowadays, and also in ones' complement, that value-preserving conversion happens to coincide with sign-extension, but if the representaion is sign-and magnitude, the conversion would be different.

Since -128 isn't representable as a signed eight-bit integer in ones' complement or sign-and magnitude, let's look at what happens to the bit-patterns when converting -127 to a 32-bit signed integer with the same kind of representation:

Two's complement:

```
10000001 -> 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000001
```

Ones' complement:

```
10000000 -> 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
```

Sign-and-magnitude:

```
11111111 -> 10000000 00000000 00000000 01111111
```

Comment: @Liang-YuPan Assuming standard two's complement and eight-bit (signed) `char`, 32-bit `int`, the bit pattern of `char i = -128;` is `10000000` or, hexadecimal `0x80`, the bit pattern of the `int` -128, regardless of whether it is obtained via a conversion from `char` or in another way, is under the above assumptions `0xFFFFFF80` (hex for brevity). So when `printf` shall print a signed integer (`%d`) and finds that bit pattern, it prints -128. When it shall interpret that bit pattern as an unsigned integer (`%u`), the value is `2^32 - 128 = 4294967168`.

Answer (score 2):

It just prints the unsigned version of -128 (of an **int** in this case).

Answer (score 1):

you force a cast to see the first byte of an integer:

```
char j = -128; 
printf("%d", (char) j);
```

to see the second byte as decimal, you force a cast either:

```
printf("%d", *(((char *) &j) + 1 ) );
```

last byte of an integer:

```
printf("%d", *(((char *) &j) + 3 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is invoking undefined behavior by passing the wrong type to `printf`. `%u` expects an `unsigned` argument but you passed a (signed) `int`. `printf` does not "know what to do" because it doesn't have to do anything in particular; it's free to do whatever happens because you invoked UB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple test program that may help you understand what's going on.  Note that it uses the C99 length modifier `hh`, which means:

> `hh` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a
>   `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have
>   been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be
>   converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); or that
>   a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `signed char`
>   argument.

This may help you understand how the types are handled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void print_value(signed char sc, unsigned char uc, /*plain*/ char pc)
{
    int j1 = sc;
    int j2 = uc;
    int j3 = pc;
    printf("%-9s  %4hhd %4hhu %4d 0x%hhX %10u\n", "Signed:",   j1, j1, j1, j1, j1);
    printf("%-9s  %4hhd %4hhu %4d 0x%hhX %10u\n", "Unsigned:", j2, j2, j2, j2, j2);
    printf("%-9s  %4hhd %4hhu %4d 0x%hhX %10u\n", "Plain:",    j3, j3, j3, j3, j3);
}

static void check_value(int i)
{
        signed    char sc = i;
        unsigned  char uc = i;
        /*plain*/ char pc = i;
        print_value(sc, uc, pc);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        check_value(i);
    for (int i = SCHAR_MAX - 3; i <= SCHAR_MAX+3; i++)
        check_value(i);
    for (int i = UCHAR_MAX - 3; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++)
        check_value(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `-fsigned-char` (so 'plain' `char` is a signed type), the output is:

```
Signed:       0    0    0 0x0          0
Unsigned:     0    0    0 0x0          0
Plain:        0    0    0 0x0          0
Signed:       1    1    1 0x1          1
Unsigned:     1    1    1 0x1          1
Plain:        1    1    1 0x1          1
Signed:       2    2    2 0x2          2
Unsigned:     2    2    2 0x2          2
Plain:        2    2    2 0x2          2
Signed:       3    3    3 0x3          3
Unsigned:     3    3    3 0x3          3
Plain:        3    3    3 0x3          3
Signed:     124  124  124 0x7C        124
Unsigned:   124  124  124 0x7C        124
Plain:      124  124  124 0x7C        124
Signed:     125  125  125 0x7D        125
Unsigned:   125  125  125 0x7D        125
Plain:      125  125  125 0x7D        125
Signed:     126  126  126 0x7E        126
Unsigned:   126  126  126 0x7E        126
Plain:      126  126  126 0x7E        126
Signed:     127  127  127 0x7F        127
Unsigned:   127  127  127 0x7F        127
Plain:      127  127  127 0x7F        127
Signed:    -128  128 -128 0x80 4294967168
Unsigned:  -128  128  128 0x80        128
Plain:     -128  128 -128 0x80 4294967168
Signed:    -127  129 -127 0x81 4294967169
Unsigned:  -127  129  129 0x81        129
Plain:     -127  129 -127 0x81 4294967169
Signed:    -126  130 -126 0x82 4294967170
Unsigned:  -126  130  130 0x82        130
Plain:     -126  130 -126 0x82 4294967170
Signed:      -4  252   -4 0xFC 4294967292
Unsigned:    -4  252  252 0xFC        252
Plain:       -4  252   -4 0xFC 4294967292
Signed:      -3  253   -3 0xFD 4294967293
Unsigned:    -3  253  253 0xFD        253
Plain:       -3  253   -3 0xFD 4294967293
Signed:      -2  254   -2 0xFE 4294967294
Unsigned:    -2  254  254 0xFE        254
Plain:       -2  254   -2 0xFE 4294967294
Signed:      -1  255   -1 0xFF 4294967295
Unsigned:    -1  255  255 0xFF        255
Plain:       -1  255   -1 0xFF 4294967295
```

Compiled with -funsigned-char`(so 'plain'`char` is an unsigned type), the output is:

```
Signed:       0    0    0 0x0          0
Unsigned:     0    0    0 0x0          0
Plain:        0    0    0 0x0          0
Signed:       1    1    1 0x1          1
Unsigned:     1    1    1 0x1          1
Plain:        1    1    1 0x1          1
Signed:       2    2    2 0x2          2
Unsigned:     2    2    2 0x2          2
Plain:        2    2    2 0x2          2
Signed:       3    3    3 0x3          3
Unsigned:     3    3    3 0x3          3
Plain:        3    3    3 0x3          3
Signed:     124  124  124 0x7C        124
Unsigned:   124  124  124 0x7C        124
Plain:      124  124  124 0x7C        124
Signed:     125  125  125 0x7D        125
Unsigned:   125  125  125 0x7D        125
Plain:      125  125  125 0x7D        125
Signed:     126  126  126 0x7E        126
Unsigned:   126  126  126 0x7E        126
Plain:      126  126  126 0x7E        126
Signed:     127  127  127 0x7F        127
Unsigned:   127  127  127 0x7F        127
Plain:      127  127  127 0x7F        127
Signed:    -128  128 -128 0x80 4294967168
Unsigned:  -128  128  128 0x80        128
Plain:     -128  128  128 0x80        128
Signed:    -127  129 -127 0x81 4294967169
Unsigned:  -127  129  129 0x81        129
Plain:     -127  129  129 0x81        129
Signed:    -126  130 -126 0x82 4294967170
Unsigned:  -126  130  130 0x82        130
Plain:     -126  130  130 0x82        130
Signed:      -4  252   -4 0xFC 4294967292
Unsigned:    -4  252  252 0xFC        252
Plain:       -4  252  252 0xFC        252
Signed:      -3  253   -3 0xFD 4294967293
Unsigned:    -3  253  253 0xFD        253
Plain:       -3  253  253 0xFD        253
Signed:      -2  254   -2 0xFE 4294967294
Unsigned:    -2  254  254 0xFE        254
Plain:       -2  254  254 0xFE        254
Signed:      -1  255   -1 0xFF 4294967295
Unsigned:    -1  255  255 0xFF        255
Plain:       -1  255  255 0xFF        255
```

Compiled with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.4 (but using the standard C libraries on the platform).